# C++ Binary character are converting to plain text

Tags: c++, file-transfer, binary-data

im sending a file using TCPSocket and its being sent correctly but
the problem is in my split function it converts the binary bytes to plain characters
if i writed the orignal received buffer to the file it gives me real bytes 100% like orignal file
i need split function to split the sent messages because some times if i sent 2 messages in same time they will be received as 1 message

what do you think what should i do?

thanks

***Solution :***

i replaced sprintf with memcpy
and it works perfectly now :) thanks everyone.

Comment: Show us the relevant bits of your code. How do you receive the files on the server? How do you send them on the client?

Comment: Your example would be more useful if you posted the actual bytes instead of an attempt to interpret them as text.

Comment: Why do you copy byte-by-byte when you can copy the whole chunk in a single operation with `memcpy`?

Comment: i did but same thing :)